# When (in the lifetime of the plant) should the first hard pruning of budleja be performed?

Tags: pruning, butterflies

I already have one budleja (butterfly bush) (it was already on the site where I started working on it), and I prune it every early spring. It grows really well every year.

However, I bought another one, which is much smaller now (but its adult size should be a normal size for a butterfly bush - 5-8 ft). I don't feel comfortable pruning it hard the next spring - it looks too smal and fragile. Should I nevertheless prune it hard next march, or perhaps wait for several years?

Comment: How small is small - can you add a photo please?

Answer (score 2):

Buddleia is known in Britain as the *bomb-site plant* because it was the first to colonize bomb sites during the WWII blitz.

It can survive severe pruning from a very young age.  I've known it in the gardens of several houses that I or my friends have owned, and have seen it regrow healthily after being pruned in its first spring.  As long as you are confident that the roots are healthy you shouldn't have a problem.